# Bootstrap4 beta: tables and d-inline-block

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to display a few tables side by side with horizontal scrolling overflow if the tables do not fit on the page.

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/c949Lspy/10/

Bootstrap: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">

<table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style=" padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr><th> Heading 1</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr><td>Row content </td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row content </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

1. The inspector tells me Bootstrap is somehow setting the width of the
   table equal to the width of the viewport. Why is that? (1st row in
   jsfiddle)
2. If i set the width of the table manualy, the table elements do
       not fill up the space, which looks awkward. (2nd row in jsfiddle)
3. How do i set the tables to fill up exactly the space they need / are
       given explicitly?

Comment: You could use the grid system.

Comment: I have more than 12 tables...

Comment: Vertical or horizontal scroll?

Comment: Horizontal. Edited.

Comment: Please provide bootstrap link

Comment: @Harper So what?

Comment: Edited in. You can also find it in the jsfiddle "external resources"

Comment: @ProEvilz How would i do that? The grid system allows only 12 cols and create a line break if the cols reach the width of the viewport. Or am i mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution. I used borders so you can understand better.

I had to simplify and edit a little the html.

https://codepen.io/mikele/pen/OxWMRq

```
table {
  border: solid blue!important;
  float: left!important;
  width: 200px!important;
}
#table-container {
 border: solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
#big {
  border: solid green;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10000px;
}
```

**Explanation**

I wrap the tables in 2 divs. First div - sets the width, say 300px, and also overflow-x to scroll. The child div sets a very wide width, so that it can fit all your floated tables.

**To calculate width for `#big`** (jQuery) :

```
var tableWidth = 200; // you can get it from a table if you like

var nrTables = $('table').length;

$('#big').css('width', (nrTables * tableWidth + 30) + 'px');
```

```js
var tableWidth = 200; // you can get it from a table if you like

    var nrTables = $('table').length;

    $('#big').css('width', (nrTables * tableWidth + 30) + 'px');
```

```css
table {
  border: solid blue!important;
  float: left!important;
  width: 200px!important;
}
#table-container {
 border: solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
#big {
  border: solid green;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="table-container" style="white-space: nowrap;">
<div id="big">

  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered d-inline-block align-top" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  </div></div>
```

Comment: Hm, what about the free space besides each table? And the free space in the right of the tables indroduce by the #big container?

Comment: To leave spaces between tables, use margins in the table styling. For the extra space at right, you can calculate how many tables you have (nr tables * width of a table), then set the width for #big, so that no extra space is left. For more questions, either try yourself, or post a new question. If my answer solved your original problem, mark it as accepted and upvote.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is i don't know the number of tables before runtime. And i asked these questions because you answer did not solve the problem ;-)

Comment: You don't need to know before runtime. Use JS. And your question was **How to do horizontal scroll**, hence you got a working answer.

Comment: The horizontal scroll was not the question. See jsfiddle, horizontal scroll is already working there. The intention of this question was to understand the behaviour of bootstrap concerning these spacings (see 1, 2, 3 in the original question)

Comment: I see now. Anyway, I edited my ans so it includes the width calculation.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT X2: Displaying differences in responsive behaviors in BS3 vs BS4**

I suggest using the grid system and table-responsive in bootstrap3.  I also suggest encapsulating your body in a container, and and the first two tables possibly in a container-fluid.  I've also removed your `d-inline-block align-top` .. Here is what I've done:

```
<div class="container" style="white-space: nowrap;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="background: #f7fec0; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
        <th> Heading 1</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="background: #cac1fd; padding: 0px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Heading 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row content </td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

[Non responsive behaviors in BS4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGUZP.png)

[Responsive working as intended in BS3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpPCY.png)

Comment: @Harper it looks fine not in jsfiddle...  Hmmm

Comment: Did you use Bootstrap4? Bootstrap3 seems to work differently in this matter.

Comment: i did use bs3 only because bs4 is in beta.  Is using a beta framework a requirement rather than a widely accepted production framework?

also you are correct, it acts differently in bs4.  I'm looking for a workaround with bs4.

Comment: @Harper i think i figured it out... editting my response

Comment: I have copied your edits to jsfiddle. Have a look, it seems the matter is more complicated than i thougt. Maybe its easier to switch to bs3 =/ https://jsfiddle.net/1hr059zw/2/

Comment: @Harper wow. It does funny things in responsive mode doesnt it... that's annoying.  I sent screenshots from BS3 and BS4 page responsive comparisons.

Comment: FYI, i have submitted this issue as a bug report. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24105